# How can I create a visual like the attached image in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am looking to display the differences between variations in queue volumes from 2017 to 2019 and I have come across a chart that I was sent from a presentation which I would like to create in R as I feel this will be the best visual to display my data.

I have tried to create a slope chart from the following URL using the sample data from the site at present:

http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Slope%20Chart

This gives me the 2 axis inside the chart but its now trying to understand how I add the colour in between in order to make it look like the attached image. I have also looked at how an area chart works, one of the URL I looked at was the following:

https://www.displayr.com/how-to-make-an-area-chart-in-r/

as the image I have seems to be a mixture of an area chart and a slope chart so thought I could try and see if there was any code from an area chart on how the colours are filled in but this only showed me the attribute it used to fill the variances.

The code that I have used is from the above URL (http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Slope%20Chart) as I replicated the data from the site, but I have struggled to make any changes to make this look like the attached image.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could advise if I am going along the right lines, or the chart that I have attached can be created using a package in R as I haven't come across or seen this visual previously. Would appreciate any support I can get.

[image: chart that I am trying to replicate]

The code that I have created (all credit to http://r-statistics.co/)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
theme_set(theme_classic())

# prep data
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/gdppercap.csv")
colnames(df) <- c("continent", "1952", "1957")
left_label <- paste(df$continent, round(df$`1952`),sep=", ")
right_label <- paste(df$continent, round(df$`1957`),sep=", ")
df$class <- ifelse((df$`1957` - df$`1952`) < 0, "red", "green")

# Plot
p <- ggplot(df) + geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=2, y=`1952`, yend=`1957`, col=class), size=.75, show.legend=F) + 
                  geom_vline(xintercept=1, linetype="dashed", size=.1) + 
                  geom_vline(xintercept=2, linetype="dashed", size=.1) +
                  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Up", "Down"), 
                                     values = c("green"="#00ba38", "red"="#f8766d")) +  # color of lines
                  labs(x="", y="Mean GdpPerCap") +  # Axis labels
                  xlim(.5, 2.5) + ylim(0,(1.1*(max(df$`1952`, df$`1957`))))  # X and Y axis limits

# Add texts
p <- p + geom_text(label=left_label, y=df$`1952`, x=rep(1, NROW(df)), hjust=1.1, size=3.5)
p <- p + geom_text(label=right_label, y=df$`1957`, x=rep(2, NROW(df)), hjust=-0.1, size=3.5)
p <- p + geom_text(label="Time 1", x=1, y=1.1*(max(df$`1952`, df$`1957`)), hjust=1.2, size=5)  # title
p <- p + geom_text(label="Time 2", x=2, y=1.1*(max(df$`1952`, df$`1957`)), hjust=-0.1, size=5)  # title

# Minify theme
p + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
           panel.grid = element_blank(),
           axis.ticks = element_blank(),
           axis.text.x = element_blank(),
           panel.border = element_blank(),
           plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,1,2), "cm"))
```

Result:

[image: Slope Chart]

Comment: I would recommend you add the data and code here as well as the result and what you've tried to modify. This might attrack more people to help. Note that while you are trying to display proportions (at least that it what's shown on the picture) the data from the example looks at absolute values.

Comment: Thanks kath, I have added the data, code and the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I think to do this is to use `geom_polygon` on a pre-constructed dataframe with cumulative sums of gdp at each time point:

```
zero_row <- tibble(continent = "0start",  # creates a row of 0's
                   year = c("1952", "1957"),
                   class  ="none",
                   gdp = 0)


df2 <- df %>% 
  gather("year", "gdp", 2:3) %>%  # separate years to new rows
  bind_rows(zero_row, .) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(y2 = cumsum(gdp)) %>%  # cumulative sum to give top y values
  arrange(continent, year)

df2[3:12, "y1"] <- df2[1:10, "y2"]  # insert bottom y values

order_df <- tibble(year = c("1952", "1952", "1957", "1957"),
                   level = c("y1", "y2", "y2", "y1"), 
                   order = 1:4)  # order to plot


p <- df2[3:12,] %>% 
  gather("level", "y", 5:6) %>%  # separate y values to new rows
  full_join(order_df, by = c("year", "level")) %>% 
  arrange(continent, order) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(year, y, fill = continent, group = continent)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1, linetype="dashed", size=.1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=2, linetype="dashed", size=.1) +
  labs(x="", y="Mean GdpPerCap") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.2*max(df2$y2)), expand = c(0 ,0))

lab_pos <- df2 %>%  # new label positions
  filter(continent !="0start") %>% 
  select(continent, year, y2) %>% 
  spread(year, y2)

# Add texts
p <- p + geom_text(data = df, label=left_label, y = lab_pos$`1952`, x=rep(1, NROW(df)), hjust=1.1, size=3.5)
p <- p + geom_text(data = df, label=right_label, y=lab_pos$`1957`, x=rep(2, NROW(df)), hjust=-0.1, size=3.5)
p <- p + geom_text(label="Time 1", x=1, y=1.1*(max(df2$`y2`)), hjust=1.2, size=5)  # title
p <- p + geom_text(label="Time 2", x=2, y=1.1*(max(df2$`y2`)), hjust=-0.1, size=5)  # title

# Minify theme
p + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,1,2), "cm"),
          legend.position = "none")
```

This produces the following plot:
[image]

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**
Ooops, forgot that the `geom_area` function exists too. Try this to start:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  gather("year", "val", 2:3) 


df2 %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year),
         continent = factor(df2$continent, levels = rev(unique(df2$continent)))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(aes(x = year, y = val, fill = continent)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1952, 1957), expand = c(0.5,0.5))
```

(in this one, `year` has to be converted to a numeric value, so mapping the rest of your labels etc. would need changed.)

Comment: there's of course a few limitations here. The y-axis labels are no longer useful, as they don't record a 'sum' of means. Also, this type of plot is best for showing changing comparative 'shares' of something - mean GDP and things like it aren't really best measured, but I do realise that's not your final output.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for looking through this for me, really appreciated. I will give that a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Andrew, that worked! Thank you so much, I am going to play around with the code and try and get rid of the axis and dotted lines but this has got me started. You are a star!

Comment: glad it helped! did you find `geom_area` or `geom_polygon` more useful in the end?

Comment: I went with the geom_polygon, but geom_area is a good option as well